# date extraction through regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string.

```
s = "20160204094836A"
```

I want to get the date as below using regex.

```
date = "20160204"
start_date = date(int("2016"), int("02"), int("04"))
```

So, In short I need to get year, day and month.
Is such thing possible through regex?

Comment: What are the rules? How did you get `02` and `04` from the above string? Is there a pattern here? I have a feeling that you *don't* need regex here.

Comment: no patttern. I just have a string and I need to extract by this way

Comment: Then extract first 4 digits, then the next pairs.

Comment: yes but I do not understand how can I do that using regex

Comment: @sam Why do you want to use regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : sry. I made changed updated now

Comment: @MarounMaroun : Thats requirement

Comment: Using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without regex:

```
s = "20160204094836A"

year = s[:4]
day = s[4:6]
month = s[6:8]

print(year, day, month)
```

With Regex:

```
import re

s = "20160204094836A"
result = re.search(r"^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})", s)
year = int(result.group(1))
day = int(result.group(2))
month = int(result.group(3))

print(year, day, month)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for this task directly:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = "20160204094836A"

start_date = datetime.strptime(s[:8], "%Y%m%d").date()
```

`start_date` will hold the finished `datetime.date` object.

`s[:8]` represents the first 8 characters of your string `s`, as `strptime()` can not handle remaining, unparsed characters.

`"%Y%m%d"` describes the pattern using which your string should be parsed.
`%Y` is a 4 digit year number ("2016"),
`%m` is a 2 digit month number ("02"),
`%d` is a 2 digit day number ("04"),

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use regex, you can use a pattern like `^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*$`

Then you can reference the matched groups, cast them to int, and pass them to date.

Since it's all just a string of numbers in that straightforward format, you may want to just do substrings instead.